# From $\tan\varphi = -3/2 = -1,5$ to $\varphi\approx 123,69^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry, calculator

Sorry for this question but what do I have to type into my counter to come from

$$\tan \varphi = -1,5 $$

to $\approx 123,69^\circ$ and $\approx 303,69^\circ$? Thanks!

Comment: i mean i tried tan`-1 but that gave me -0.02618..

Comment: oh sorry its simple -1.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve for $\theta$ you can use $\arctan(-3/2) = -\arctan(3/2)$.

To convert from radians to degrees, you multiply by $\frac{180^\circ}{\pi}$: $$x\text{ radians} \times \dfrac {180^\circ}{\pi} = y^\circ$$

Comment: do you know the name of the arctan key on casio counters?

Comment: It is also denoted by $\tan^{-1}$: The inverse tangent function.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives $\approx -56.31^\circ$: adding $180^\circ$ gives one possible angle: $\theta \approx 123.69^\circ$ and adding $360^\circ$ gives the other $\approx 303.69^\circ$, both within the interval $[0, 360^\circ]$.

Comment: Oh thanks now i understand it!